# Sphinx search with Character Sets

Tags: php, search, sphinx

How can i use search $keyword like gr[ae]y to match either gray or grey in Sphinx.

Is it possible to use "character class" similar to regex.

ps: I dont wanna send manually gray | grey string for $keyword

Actually i wanna eliminate spelling mistakes like i-ı or c-ç.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Wordforms is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually i wanna eliminate spelling mistakes like i-ı or c-ç. not really wordforms that i needed cause there is multiple combination for search string.

Comment: You could probably get away with using `charset_table` to fold c-ç and i-ı - to make them equivient. But that wont help a-e you can't just make those two letters interchangable. It could drastically change the meaning of words. Would still suggest gray/grey is a special case (just like say color/colour) to handle with wordforms.